Why does this C function use of stdarg breaks when compiled by clang for Apple Silicon?
The following function MsCommand_push does not work as expected when compiled with Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4). It is supposed to take as input a variable number of pointer to char (pointing to null-terminating strings) and append them to a buffer. It is part of a command line interpreter and its purpose is to fill a buffer with a string that will be used to launch processes.
The function uses the stdarg.h types and macros. It works as expected on Linuces (compiled with gcc), Windows (compiled with gcc), macOS x86-64 (compiled with clang). It has been working as expected for decades under those environments and others such as SunOS and other UNIX flavors.
On macOS arm64, compiled with clang 15, the assignment to str sometimes does not retrieve the first element of the remaining parameters.
/* global variables accessed in the function */
static char *cmd_buffer = NULL;
static int buffer_size = 0;
static int cmd_len = 0;
static int free_len = 0;
static const int init_buffer_size = 1024;

/* typical call: MsCommand_push(1, "cp "); */
void MsCommand_push(unsigned nb, ...)
{
    int new_len = 0;
    const char *str = NULL;
    char *tmp = NULL;
    unsigned int i = 0;

    va_list param;
    va_list param2;
    va_start(param, nb);
    va_copy(param2,param);

    for (i=0; i < nb; i++)
    {
        str = va_arg(param, char *); /* <--- va_arg returns garbage in first iteration! */
        new_len = new_len + strlen(str);
    }

    va_end(param);

    if (free_len < new_len)
    {
        char *tmp = cmd_buffer;
        cmd_buffer = calloc(cmd_len + result, sizeof(char));
        memcpy(cmd_buffer, tmp, cmd_len * sizeof(char));
        buffer_size = cmd_len + result;
        free_len = result;
    }

    ASSERT(cmd_len > 0);
    tmp = cmd_buffer + cmd_len - 1;

    str = NULL;
    for (i=0; i < nb; i++)
    {
        str = va_arg(param2, char *);
        sprintf(tmp, "%s", str);
        tmp = tmp + strlen(str);
    }

    va_end(param2);

    cmd_len = new_len + cmd_len;
    free_len = free_len - new_len;
}

/* function called before MsCommand_push */
void MsCommand_init() {
    ASSERT((cmd_buffer == NULL) && (init_buffer_size > 0));

    cmd_buffer = (char *)malloc(init_buffer_size);
    free_len = init_buffer_size - 1;
    cmd_len = 1;
    cmd_buffer[0] = '\0';
    buffer_size = init_buffer_size;
}

To make the problem more self-contained and easier to reproduce, I changed the code so that the faulty behavior occurs in a much more simple context than in the actual cases.
To do so, I wrote the following main function:
int main(int argc,
         char **argv)
{
    extern int MsFile_dummy1();
    extern void MsCommand_push(unsigned nb, ...);
    extern void MsCommand_init();
    MsCommand_init();
    MsCommand_push(1, "cp ");

    if (MsFile_dummy1() == 1) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

The call to MsCommand_push from main works as expected.
However the call through MsFile_dummy1() falls into the anomalous behavior. This function is just a proxy to include the call:
In another file, we have
int MsFile_dummy1() {
    MsCommand_push(1, "cp ");
    return 0;
}

What could be wrong and how could I fix this issue?
Note: I found a 10-year old discussion on this topic and I suppose it is not up-to-date.

please provide a minimal reproducible example.

I don't see declarations for free_len, cmd_buffer, buffer_size.  You don't have to use va_copy(); you could reuse param with a second va_start(), but that's very unlikely to be your problem.

My guess is you have undefined behavior somewhere else in the program, and it's triggering unrelated problems here. It's inconceivable that clang would have problems with basic use of stdarg.

Your usage of stdargs looks fine to me.  It does seem very unlikely that Clang has a flaw that would bear on that.  The issue, then, is probably related to the cmd_buffer, cmd_len, and free_len variables, or to the function parameters passed on some call.  For instance, if free_len or nb is too large, or if one of the argument strings is unterminated, then you might have any manner of unexpected behavior -- or not.

Does Apples version of clang support sanitizers? Adding  -fsanitize=address,undefined to the compilation options might help track down the issue if so.

@JonathanLeffler I have edited the question to add the declarations. The problem also happens when param is reused with a second call to va_start.

With regard to the old Q&A linked at the end of this question: the misbehavior observed there is likely to have been a matter of the author calling functions that were declared incompatibly with their definitions.  They note in their question, "I failed to mention a key element to this issue that I didn't think to mention before. I was attempting to swizzle non-variadic functions with a generic variadic function."  C does not define any way to call a non-variadic function as if it were a variadic one, or vice versa.

It looks like you forgot about the terminatting null character. You only add strlens

What does s_realloc() do?  Does the code fail on the call you show?  What sequence of calls does it take to show the crash?  This is the sort of information that makes up part of an MCVE (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example
— or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE (Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example
— the same idea by a different name).

@0___________ The terminating null character is already counted for in cmd_len. It is correct to add the result of strlen as it is enough to copy each character in the C-string pointed to by str.
By the way, the error occurs the first time MsCommand_push is called, when the value of i is 0, as the pointer assigned to str (the result of the first call to va_arg) is invalid. So this is before cmd_buffer has been accessed in this function.

@JonathanLeffler s_realloc is a macro definition to call a function called s_persistent_realloc... which itself calls the stdlib function realloc nested between two calls to tracing functions.
Sorry for not providing all the context, this code is part of a much larger code base, that started its life the past millenium (this part of the code has been working perfectly for a few decades...). And the clang compiler for arm64 must be handling some undefined behavior differently from other compilers. I fear that the context I have given in my question is not enough to identify it.

@JonathanLeffler I have replaced s_realloc with similar code that only uses standard library services (and the reported problem still occurs).

@Shawn Thanks for the tip. I have used the sanitizers you suggested. They have been helpful to identify a couple of issues, but fixing those did not resolve the question discussed here.

The cause for this problem is that the declaration of the variadic function MsCommand_push is not visible when function MsFile_dummy1 is compiled.
The root cause is that the proper header file had not been included... and the compiler flags included -Wno-implicit-function-declaration.
Thank you for all the helpful comments that pushed me to do a deeper investigation of this problem.

Well done on finding the problem.  I couldn't reproduce it, but I was compiling with a command line clang -Wno-nullability-completeness -O3 -g -std=c18 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-common stdarg43.c -o stdarg43.  The -no-nullability-completeness option is a peculiarity on this particular Mac (an M3 MacBook Pro running macOS Sonoma 14.7.1).  The rest of the options are more or less what I always use — and the -Werror ensures I don't run anything that doesn't compile cleanly.  Make sure you use a similarly stringent set of compiler options.
